# how to do an event when any update is accrues in my database ( laravel )

Tags: php, laravel, events

Is thereany way to do an event to detect if user updates his information?

I need to do an event when any record is  updated.

What i did is in each modal

```
public static function boot(){
    parent::boot();


 static::updating(function($model){ // not working
      dd(1);

});

static::saving(function($model){ //work fine
   dd(1);

  });


 }
```

`static::updating` is not working with me

Any example for how can i do that please?

Comment: What kind of operation are trying to achieve. Application or database level?

Comment: i need to insert record to database after updating my model ( database)

Comment: Which version of Laravel are you using? Have you tried replacing `static::updating` with `static::updated` ? Your events doesn't make sense a bit, because in Laravel official documentation is written : Whenever a new model is saved for the first time, the creating and created events will fire. If a model already existed in the database and the save method is called, the updating / updated events will fire. **However, in both cases, the saving / saved events will fire.** So you probably got event fired, but both events fired after update.

Comment: According to the Laravel docs, a `saving` event is fired every time you create or update a record. So i think you listening to the updating event is useless. https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent#events